# setcookie not setting if path is set to "/"

Tags: php, wordpress, http, cookies

Im using `setcookie("test_cookie", $value, $expires, '/', $domain);` to set my cookie but it's not working.

If i use my $domain as $path and not filling out $domain, its setting the cookie, but not with the right options, obviously. Which makes me think the $path or $domain is not working as intented.

What im looking for: Make php make a cookie with a value that works on every page of my website, but I don't know if im writing bad code or it's something with my server settings.

Comment: What kind of syntax are you using for your url in ``$domain`` ? setcookie() cares about subdomains or https, ``$domain`` should be like : ``example.com``

Comment: Im using .example.com to target all domains. I guess you could be right, because when creating a cookie without $domain, it actually creates one.